# No such method error while calling a function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I retrieved products data from Firebase for my E-commerce homepage  through future builder. I've created another screen that displays more information on a product when the user clicks on a product  from the E-commerce homepage.To navigate to more information screen i created a function called showProduct and called it with a button, but when the button id pressed it shows
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.Receiver: null Tried calling .
The showProduct function ] was also used on the vendor profile page where the products shown are shown in gridview and when clicked on any product from the vendors's profile.The showProduct function works and open more information screen.

E-commerce Homepage:

```
c

lass Shop extends StatefulWidget {

  final Prod products;
  final User currentUser;
  final String prodId;
  final String onwerId;
  Shop({ this.currentUser,
    this.prodId,
    this.products,
    this.onwerId});

  @override
  _ShopState createState() => _ShopState( prodId: this.prodId,products: this.products,ownerId:this.onwerId);
}

class _ShopState extends State<Shop> {

  String postOrientation = "grid";
  String shopOrientation = "grid";
  bool isFollowing = false;
  bool isLoading = false;
  String uid="";
  String prodId;
  String ownerId;
  Prod products;
  _ShopState({
    this.prodId, this.products,this.ownerId,
  });

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showProduct;
  }

  Future getProducts()async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot snap = await firestore.collectionGroup("userProducts").getDocuments();
    return snap.documents;
  }
  Future<Null>getRefresh()async{
    await Future.delayed(Duration (seconds : 3));
    setState(() {
      getProducts();
    });
  }
  showProduct(context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ProductScreen(
          prodId: prodId,
          userId: ownerId,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(backgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
          title: Text(   'Shop',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily :"MajorMonoDisplay",
                fontSize:  35.0 ,
                color: Colors.white),),
          iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: kSecondaryColor),
        ),
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        body:FutureBuilder(
            future: getProducts(),
            builder: (context,snapshot)
            {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(child: circularProgress(),);
              } else {
                return
                  RefreshIndicator(
                      onRefresh: getRefresh,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            var ourdata = snapshot.data[index];
                            return
                              Container(
                                height: 500,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 1.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 1.0),
                                child: Column( children: <Widget>[
                                  SizedBox( height:1.0,),
                                Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                child:Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(
                                  child: Container(
                                  height: 400.0,
                                  child: ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                    child: cachedNetworkImage(ourdata.data['shopmediaUrl'],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                            ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                            child: Positioned(
                            bottom: 10,
                            left: 10,
                            child: Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                            child: Image.network(ourdata.data['photoUrl'],)),
                            ),
                            ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                            child: Positioned(
                            bottom: 20,
                            left: 60,
                            child: Container(
                            child: Text(ourdata.data['username'],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),),
                            ),
                            ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            child: GFButton(
                             onPressed: () => showProduct(context) ,
                            text: "More",
                            icon: Icon(Icons.card_travel),
                            shape: GFButtonShape.pills,
                            ),
                            ),
                            ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                            child: Text(ourdata.data['productname'],style: TextStyle(color: kText,fontSize: 30.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),),
                            ),
                            ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                            Container(  child: Text('₹',style: TextStyle(color: kText,)),
                            ),
                            Container(
                            child: Text(ourdata.data['price'],style: TextStyle(color: kText,fontSize: 20.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),),
                            ),
                            ],
                            ),
                            Divider(color: kGrey,),
                            ],
                            ),
                            );
                          }
                      )
                  );
              }
            }
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
          onPressed: ()
          async{ Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>Uploadecom(currentUser: currentUser, )));
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add_box),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

This is the gridview on the vendor's profile.

```
 class ProductTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Prod products;

  ProductTile(this.products);

  showProduct(context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ProductScreen(
          prodId: products.prodId,
          userId: products.ownerId,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => showProduct(context),
      child: cachedNetworkImage(products.shopmediaUrl),
    );
  }
}
```

If  you need more codes please ask me.

Comment: also check for if snapshot has error using `snapshot.haserror` and use `StreamBuilder` for firebase and you don't need to pass data to state you can directly access data using `widget.yourData`

Comment: Can you explain with code ?

Comment: I do t think snapshot has an error because im getting the required data but only the showProduct function doesn't work

Comment: Took your advise and used 'StreamBuilder'.showProduct worked but show profile didn't work.Thanks

Comment: provide code of show profile i will try to help you

Comment: ShowProduct works' showProduct(context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ProductScreen(
          prodId: prodId,
          userId: ownerId,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }'
'showProfile( context) {
   Navigator.push(
       context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Profile(
            profileId: ownerId,
          )));
  }'

Comment: can you help me with this issue <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62452900/the-method-where-isnt-defined-for-the-type-documentreference>