# " the method where isn't defined for the type documentreference"?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

why i'm i getting this error " the method where isn't defined for the type documentreference"?
is there any other way to filter documents?

```
 buildPostHeader() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future:Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(id).where('designer',isEqualTo:true).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(

              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0,left: 10.0,right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0 ),

          child: Column(
            children:  <Widget> [
              ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                ),
                title: Text(user.displayName,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                subtitle: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => showProfile(context, profileId: user.id),
                  child: Text(
                    user.username,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: kText,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with above code -
You are specifing an document Id so you will get a single document and `where` can only be applied to `List` or `Iterable`

```
  Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('designer',isEqualTo:true).getDocuments(),
```

Try to use this code it will return a `Future<QuerySnapShot>` and `snapshot.data.documents` is a `List<DocumentSnapShot>` which passed the where condition if you want to filter it again by id or something else you can do it by using `where` to `snapshot.data.documents`

```
final data = snapshot.data.documents.where(condition);
```